# Force button to look pressed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a UIButton, and I need to programmatically make it looked like how it looks when my finger is on it (darker).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an easier way. Just use "performSelector" with 0 delay to perform [button setHighlighted:YES] . This will perform re-highlighting after the current runloop ends.

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"selected %@",sender.titleLabel.text);
    [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)b {
    [b setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourButton.selected = YES;
yourButton.highlighted = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set the "highlight" property to "YES":

```
button.highlighted = YES;
```

Or you can set a selected image for the button's normal state:

```
[button setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option, if you want to set a different image for button selection, then set image for `UIControlStateSelected` and assign selected property to true programmatically.

For eg:

```
[button setImage:imageOfClicked forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setSelected:YES];
```